# How to jump onto all authority drones?

Tags: rage

Around the RAGE world map I found various authority drones. It seems that jump onto them with my car triggers some message and I imagine that there is a price if I get them all.

Unfortunately there are some drones that I was not able to reach. Maybe it depends on car or maybe I choose wrong jump platforms, I don't know.

Is there a guide that can help me do destroy all drones?

Comment: There's an immediate prize for each drone destroyed, actually, in the form of crafting components.

Comment: @Aubergine Interesting, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few helpful guides found on [TrueAchievements.com](http://www.trueachievements.com/) for *RAGE's* [Jumper achievement](http://www.trueachievements.com/a155165/jumper-achievement.htm).

For most of them, you just need to take your car and zip up a ramp at near full speed to hit them. Only 2 or 3 are really challenging.